# how to get current controllers in UIPageViewController

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller, ibooks

I am creating a book like iBook. I load data on `UIWebView` placed on contentviewcontroller. My problem is that user can go to any page through table of contents also can increase or decrase size or can highlight the text. My problem is to recognize on which `UIWebView` this is doing. or if user jump to page other page get populated with data automatically with next page. or On increase or decrease font size the data should be populated automatically. Main problem is I am not getting to retrieve the contents of different page programmatically an reload them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the pdf book reader from the leaves tutorial series. check out the link [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) and [leaves with mode](https://github.com/hammerlyrodrigo/leaves) also check the good one tutorial http://www.vfr.org/. the app loads pdf file at once and you can set your event of jump to page book mark page

Answer (score 0):

I think ,You use dataSouce of pageViewController... and solve your Problem

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:
(UIViewController *)viewController

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

how to use dataSouce of pageViewController ,for help see tutorial

Comment: I am using the same but not help me as i have series of function calling in it here is the code